# How to create an Excel Ribbon "Tab Group" with VSTO and C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

When I add a chart to an Excel file and then select that chart, two new tabs show up on the ribbon, `DESIGN` and `FORMAT` and above the tabs, I see the "tab group" title `CHART TOOLS` with a green background and bar above the name.

How can I create this "tab group" functionality in my own Add-In? I can't find any settings or properties that allow me to do this.

Here is what I'm talking about...
[image]

Comment: Nothing useful here: https://www.google.com/#q=VSTO+Excel+ribbon  ?

Comment: Interesting question. Doing a quick search, it's clear that you can add to existing contextual tabs, e.g., adding a tab to the chart tools, but it seems like you can't create a whole new contextual tab set.

Comment: @TimWilliams - hahaha... nope. nothing anywhere related to grouping those tabs. have searched all over. to be clear, i can create the tabs no problem. my specific question is about the green `CHART TOOLS` part of the above picture.

Comment: @DougGlancy - yep, that's what i was finding too. i just can't find any mention of it anywhere. seems like there should be a way to do this... maybe?

Comment: @gotmike - sorry my flippant comment was a result of mis-reading your question.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd948578(v=office.12).aspx suggests what you want might not be possible.  "This element specifies a contextual tab set control. As the id and idQ attributes are not present, this element can only be used to refer to existing built-in tab sets. *This element cannot be used to create new contextual tab sets.*"

Comment: @TimWilliams, that does seem definitive. I read right past the first line of that page. I also read somewhere in a discussion that it is possible in Access but not in Word/Excel.